# Одинарный вывод сообщения в цикле foreach - C#

Tags: c#

Есть некий код банкомата, где пользователю необходимо сначала ввести свой ид.

```
        Bankomat[] banks = new Bankomat[] { new Bankomat(146251, 1500, 15, "Петров Иван Иванович"),
                                            new Bankomat(146252, 3400, 80, "Сергеев Александр Сергеевич"),
                                            new Bankomat(146253, 710, 55, "Леонтьев Петр Евгеньевич")};

        Console.Write("Введите ваш id пожалуйста: ");

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string Y = "Y";
        int money = 0;
        string acc = "";

        foreach (Bankomat x in banks)
            if (id == x.id)
            {
               ..../*Тут не важно*/
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Вы еще не зарегистрированы в нашей системе, обратитесь к оператору \n");
                break;
            }
```

Если ввести ид Петра Евгеньевича, то сначала 2 раза выведет, что я не зарегистрирован, а потом работа с банкоматом. Как нормально сделать?

Comment: `Как нормально сделать?` - а как надо чтоб было?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Ну если я введу ид Петра, то про регистрацию вообще не должно выдавать

Answer (score 2):

Проще простого.

```
if(banks.Where(x=>x.Id==Id).FirstOrDefault()!=null)
{
 Console.Write("Вы еще не зарегистрированы в нашей системе, обратитесь к оператору \n");

}
```

Comment: Локальная переменная или параметр с именем "x" нельзя объявить в данной области, так как это имя используется во включающей локальной области для определения локальной переменной или параметра

Comment: @dadyaSasha: Ну так переименуйте формальный параметр лямбды.

Answer (score 1):

В цикле у вас каждый объект поочередно проверяется на соответствие условию `id == x.id`, поэтому выводится 2 раза, что пользователь не зарегистрирован.

Чтобы исправить это нужно сначала проверить на соответствие все элементы массива, а затем уже выполнять нужный код. Для этого можно воспользоваться LINQ методом [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
if (banks.Any(b => id == b.id))
{
   ..../*Тут не важно*/
}
else
{
    Console.Write("Вы еще не зарегистрированы в нашей системе, обратитесь к оператору \n");
}
```

---

Если вам нужно не только проверить наличие объекта в массиве, а еще и обратиться к его свойствам, то это делается так:

```
var bankomat = banks.FirstOrDefault(b => id == b.id);
if(bankomat != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Здравствуйте {bankomat.name}");
}
else
{
    Console.Write("Вы еще не зарегистрированы в нашей системе, обратитесь к оператору \n");
}
```

P.S. Избавьтесь от `foreach`, в нем нет нужды.

Comment: в этом случае, если ввожу ид 146253, то мне выводит данные от ид 146251

Comment: можем связаться в вк?

Comment: @dadyaSasha, Значит что-то не так делаете. Приведите измененный код.

Comment: foreach (Bankomat x in banks)
                if (banks.Any(b => id == b.id))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Здравствуйте {x.name}, вы находитесь на {Bankomat.adress}.");
                    while (Y == "Y"|| Y=="y")
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.Write("Вы еще не зарегистрированы в нашей системе, обратитесь к оператору \n");
                    break;
                }

Comment: @dadyaSasha, Обновил ответ.

Comment: скопировал то, что вы написали - опять данные от другого ид

Answer (score 0):

В коде вопроса Вы выводите сообщение о ненайденом счете на каждой итерации цикла. К выводу о том, что счет не найден, можно прийти только после того, как цикл завершится.

```
Bankomat found = null;
foreach (Bankomat x in banks)
{
  if (id == x.id)
  {
    found = x;
    break;
  }
}

if (found != null)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Здравствуйте " + found.name);
  /* Тут не важно */
}
else
{
  Console.Write("Вы еще не зарегистрированы в нашей системе, обратитесь к оператору \n");
}
```